# python trouble with regex

Tags: python, regex

```
bd=raw_input('Enter your birthday(Use "." to seperate between day,month and year): ')
     for match in re.finditer('/.',bd):
     print "found"
```

the following code should print found twice when I write "12.3.1990" but it prints nothing
And I cant seem to find the problem, can someone help me?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a *backslash* to escape the `.` operator and match a literal `.`:

```
for match in re.finditer('\.', bd):
```

Your code looked for a literal forward slash and any other character except a newline.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> list(re.finditer('\.', '2013.10.29'))
[<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100e8ad98>, <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x100eaf308>]
```

Comment: How can I split the date using regex?